# How to map objects dynamically in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I need help on hibernate mapping for a bean property refers to multiple classes.

In my application we are implementing permissions. These permission are not specific to certain user it may based on groups(contains list of users) and roles. So, Permissions will apply to users, roles and groups.

Following are ddl and entity classes. Please review and help me.

DDL:

```
--stores the application users
CREATE TABLE users (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    CONSTRAINT uk_users_name UNIQUE (name)
);

--stores the application groups
CREATE TABLE groups (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    CONSTRAINT uk_groups_name UNIQUE (name)
);

--stores the application roles
CREATE TABLE roles (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    CONSTRAINT uk_roles_name UNIQUE (name)
);

--stores the application object types
CREATE TABLE app_object_types (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    CONSTRAINT uk_app_object_types_name UNIQUE (name)
);

INSERT INTO app_object_types (name) VALUES ('USERS');
INSERT INTO app_object_types (name) VALUES ('GROUPS');
INSERT INTO app_object_types (name) VALUES ('ROLES');


CREATE TABLE app_permissions (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    object_type_id integer REFERENCES app_object_types(id),  -- To represent the object type 
    object_id integer, -- Objecct_id refers users -> id, groups -> id, roles - id
    permission_name text,
    CONSTRAINT uk_permissions UNIQUE (object_type_id, object_id, permission_name)
);
```

Entity Classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private int name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(int name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Groups {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private int name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(int name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Roles {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private int name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(int name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "app_object_types")
public class AppObjectTypes {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private int name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(int name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "app_permissions")
public class AppPermissions {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private String permissionName;

    @ManyToOne
    private AppObjectTypes appObjectTypes;

    private int objectId;

    private Class<?> dependentObject;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPermissionName() {
        return permissionName;
    }

    public void setPermissionName(String permissionName) {
        this.permissionName = permissionName;
    }

    public AppObjectTypes getAppObjectTypes() {
        return appObjectTypes;
    }

    public void setAppObjectTypes(AppObjectTypes appObjectTypes) {
        this.appObjectTypes = appObjectTypes;
    }

    public int getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public void setObjectId(int objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

    public Class<?> getDependentObject() {
        return dependentObject;
    }

    public void setDependentObject(Class<?> dependentObject) {
        this.dependentObject = dependentObject;
    }
}
```

I want to map user (or) group (or) role bean object to AppPermissions -> dependentObject using hibernate. I don't know it is possible or not please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you consider the use of `@Inheritance` here on your `AppPermission` entity in order to specialize each subclass based on the dependent object types.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "OBJECT_TYPE")
public class AppPermission {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue 
  private Long permissionId;
  private String name;
  @Column(name = "OBJECT_TYPE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private String objectType;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("USER")
public class UserAppPermission extends AppPermission {
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private User user;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ROLE")
public class RoleAppPermission extends AppPermission {
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private Role role;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("GROUP")
public class GroupAppPermission extends AppPermission {
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private Group group;
}
```

The first difference here with these mappings from yours is that your `AppPermission` table will be constructed differently from your current schema and would look like the following (note 4 tables):

```
Table: AppPermission
  id NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
  name VARCHAR(255)
  OBJECT_TYPE VARCHAR(31)

Table: UserAppPermission
  id NOT NULL BIGINT (FK -> AppPermission)
  user_id NOT NULL BIGINT (FK -> User)

Table: RoleAppPermission
  id NOT NULL BIGINT (FK -> AppPermission)
  role_id NOT NULL BIGINT (FK -> Role)

Table: GroupAppPermission
  id NOT NULL BIGINT (FK -> AppPermission)
  group_id NOT NULL BIGINT (FK -> Group)
```

The whole point of a database is to help us maintain referential integrity.  That's why when a table depends on a row from another table, the dependent table rows that relate to the row you wish to remove should be removed first to avoid constraint violations.  This is precisely why I have split the relations into separate tables and here I've defined each relation as "optional=false" so that basically it represents a join-table.

Another additional benefit is that if your `AppPermission` has attributes you need to store specific to the type of dependent object, you can freely add those attributes to the subclass and those attributes are stored separately in that specific subclass's table.

This setup also eliminates your `AppObjectType` table because that is now driven as part of Hibernate's discriminator pattern.  Be aware that if you have other "object-types" you'll need to introduce their specific implementations too with this setup.

Lastly, I exposed (which you don't have to) the `OBJECT_TYPE` as an non-insertable and non-updatable field because Hibernate manages that for you.  But I've exposed it allowing you to make polymorphic queries and determine the object type of the resulting object without having to perform instanceof checks if you wish.